# Javascript - Change suggested text before placing it in the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I have a html textbox that uses a javascript autocomplete feature in jQuery UI - v1.11.4. The suggested string for the textbox  is a concatenation of several columns (patient_no,patient_name,age and residence) from a table in my database. I wanted to truncate part of the string since I only require the patient_no column placed in my textbox.

Possible text suggestion : '**00032 >> Tom Michael >> 14yrs >> Westlands**'

What I want placed in the textbox : '**00032**'

Below is my code

```
//html
 <input name="patientNo" id="patientNo" type="text"   />




//autocomplete.php
    $pat_no_seq_result = pg_query("SELECT patient_no  || ' >> ' || surname || ' ' || other_name || ' >> ' || (current_date-year_of_birth)/365 || 'yrs' || ' >> '||residence FROM hp_outpatient_register;");
    $dname_list = array();
    while ($row = pg_fetch_row($pat_no_seq_result)) {
        $dname_list[] = $row[0] ;
    }





//javascript
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var availableTags = <?php include('autocomplete.php'); ?>;
            $("#patientNo").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags,//autoFocus: true
                select: function(event, ui) {
                getPatientNo(ui.item.value);
            }
            });

            function getPatientNo(value) {
            var patNo = value.substring(0, value.indexOf(' '));
            document.getElementById("patientNo").value = patNo;
        }
        });
    </script>
```

Is there any way I can truncate the string selected by user before placing it in the text field. If there is a better way from what I'm using, please advise.

Comment: @rz3r0 I'm able to use that method, but the text placed in the textbox is the whole string; not the truncated output.

Comment: What you're doing is correct. Not that it's "better" but you could put your function call into a single line. So just $("#patientNo").val(ui.item.value.split(" ")[0]);

Answer (score 0):

I solved something similar but my server side is Django. I have not used php but I assume you could return a list objects with the following structure:

```
var label = $.rowpatientNo + ' >> ' + $row.surname + ' >> ' + ' ' + $row.other_name + ' >> ' + $row.age;

//Structure
{'id': $row.patientNo, 'label': label, 'value': $row.patientNo}
```

Where the 'label' is what you want to appear in the suggestions and 'value' is what you want to appear in the text box after selecting a suggestion.

The age would have to be formatted in the query or after the query using the current_date and year_of_birth fields.